# How represent a dictionary of one hot encodded elements?

Tags: python, dictionary, pytorch, one-hot-encoding

Probably this question is asked earlier, but I could not find. I want to be able to represent an input element as one hot encoded entity.

For that, do I need to create a dictionary of one hot encoded items? Or, how can I make sure, each time one new-word is coming that will be represented by a correct encoded element without a problem? Do I need to build a dictionary? How I can I handle unknown?

For example,

```
category = set(["Sweden", "Iceland", "Germany"])


My input: Sweden
Output  : 1, 0, 0

My input: Germany 
Output  : 0, 0, 1

My input: Poland  (unknown)
Output  : 0, 0, 0
```

Can someone please put some lights on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to logically implement the encoder ?

Comment: Hi @Kris, Thanks for help. No. I want to be able to use <from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder>

Answer (score 0):

I think, simplest was to use torch with a dictionary.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

my_list = ["unknown", "hello", "world", "this", "is", "a", "test"]
print(my_list)

dictionary = {}
for i, element in enumerate(my_list):
    dictionary[element] = i
    
print(dictionary)

num_classes = len(x) + 1
F.one_hot(x, num_classes)

# query: world

F.one_hot(torch.tensor(dictionary.get("world", "unknown"), num_classes)
```

Comment: I am unsure how to handle unknown entries. Can someone help?

Comment: The handling of unknown data labels will be different depending on your use case. You may choose to exclude these data entirely, to assign them to a separate class, to underweight them during training, etc. A bit more information on your use case might help yield a better solution to the unknown data

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, one just needs the set of categories as a list:

```
all_categories = list(set(["Sweden", "Iceland", "Germany"]))
print(all_categories)
# Out: ['Germany', 'Sweden', 'Iceland']
```

Given categories as a list of unique names:

```
def hotEncode(cat, all_categories): # assuming all_categories is a list
   r =[0]*len(all_categories) # array of zeros
   if cat in all_categories:
       n = all_categories.index(cat)
       r[n] = 1
   return r

hotEncode("Iceland", all_categories)
# Out: [0, 0, 1]

hotEncode("Poland", all_categories)
# Out: [0, 0, 0]
```